# Serial.readline - out of memory

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port, arduino

I am reading from an Arduino, which is sending text through the USB port.  The Arduino sends the status of it's outputs every second. On the command received event I set a couple of checkboxes (either shutter open or mains on, or lights on) and also it outputs the data it received to a multiline text box.
Anyway.... it all works, for a few seconds, then slows down and eventually after about 10 minutes I get a Out of Memory exception. I cant figure out whats going wrong, I assume its in the class that reads the serial data - so here is that code, can anybody see anything wrong?

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace WOCA.Core.SerialComms
{
    internal class ArduinoCommunicator : ICommunicator
    {
        public event EventHandler<CommsEventsArg> CommandReceived;

    internal ArduinoCommunicator(string comPort)
    {
        Port = new SerialPort(comPort) {BaudRate = 9600, DtrEnable = true};
        Port.DataReceived += PortOnDataReceived;
    }

    private SerialPort Port { get; set; }


    public bool IsOpen { get; set; }


    public void Open()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Port.IsOpen)
            {
                Port.Open();
                IsOpen = true;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidSerialCommsException("Serial port already open");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new InvalidSerialCommsException("Serial Port error: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        try
        {
            if (Port.IsOpen)
            {
                Port.Close();
                IsOpen = false;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidSerialCommsException("Serial port not open");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw new InvalidSerialCommsException("Serial port error");
        } 

    }

    public void SendCommand(string command)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Port.IsOpen)
            {
                Port.Write(command);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidSerialCommsException("Serial port not open");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw new InvalidSerialCommsException("Serial port error, the command has not been sent");
        }

    }

    private void PortOnDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs serialDataReceivedEventArgs)
    {
        SerialPort serialPort = sender as SerialPort;

        if (serialPort != null)
        {
            string command = serialPort.ReadLine();
            command = command.Remove(command.Length-1,1);
            CommsEventsArg args = new CommsEventsArg(command);
            OnCommandReceived(args);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnCommandReceived(CommsEventsArg e)
    {
        EventHandler<CommsEventsArg> handler = CommandReceived;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Show us where you attach to `CommandReceived` and the method that responds to it.

Comment: Have you tried to find where does you receive this exception. I mean at which line?

Comment: It could be a platform bug. The serial driver code could be using an uninitalized pointer at some point. You could try to surround the ReadLine() in a try/catch block and ignore the OOM exceptions?

Comment: There are about 5 methods that subscribe to the CommandReceievd event but all they do is set a checkbox to true or false or print the data received to a textbox. How do I find where it is running out of memory?  If I hit the pause button whilst it is hanging (Before the error occurs) then it is at the CommandReceivedHandler method - which is where I would expect it to be!

Comment: It seems to be hanging on this line:  txtbxMessages.AppendText(txtbxMessages.Text + e.Command + Environment.NewLine) ;

Comment: Don't skip the hard requirement to call Control.BeginInvoke() in your event handler, this event is fired on a worker thread.  If you don't do anything to prevent the TextBox from storing an unreasonable amount of text then you can certainly get your program to slow down to a crawl.   It will stop painting first, getting OOM should take a while but is certainly possible.

Comment: This is what I have             private void CommandReceivedHandler(object sender, CommsEventsArg e)
        {
            Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
                {
                    txtbxMessages.AppendText(txtbxMessages.Text + e.Command + Environment.NewLine) ;
                });
        }

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused by the implementation of the class SerialPort. It may never never gives to control to other threads so the finalization thread cannot finalize the objects and free the memory. See my article about it: http://alexatnet.com/articles/net-memory-management-and-garbage-collector#best-practices

To fix it you need to add

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Join(100)
```

For example, it may be added to `PortOnDataReceived`. This will allow finalization thread to run pending finalizers.